# Getting Django Admin class variables from a view

Tags: django, admin

I'd like to get the values in class variables like list_display and list_filter from a view. Something like:

```
def some_view():
    print Order.list_display 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want access to associated ModelAdmin objects from the model instance? How about this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
print admin.site._registry[Order].list_display
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks.